# Creating box having css arrow using css3

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 18px;
  width: 8em;
  height: 6em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(77, 77, 77);
  color: #FF1919;
  background-color: pink;
}
.box:hover {
  width: 8em;
  margin: 18px;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  left: 18px;
  right: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 30%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 30%;
  margin-top: -18px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I have created one arrow and in that I want to highlight the arrow head with blue colour which is grey.

I also want to use this total arrow as a button to navigate to next scene page with html extension.

For that I am using:

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 40px; bottom: 70px;">
    <form action="abc.html" align="right" style="margin-right:100px ;   display:inline">
        <input type="submit" class="box"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

but it is taking a single part of that css object(rectangle) box and leaving other portions.

Comment: Although this may not be exactly what you're looking for, it may help: http://jsfiddle.net/y03cc5ty/3/

Comment: It is good but i need the exact button which i have mentioned earlier.

Comment: why don't you change the `.box:after` to `border-color: transparent transparent transparent blue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigation you can add `<a>` tag in your html page and for color of the class `.box:after` change the border color as below:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank"><div class="box"></div></a>
```

CSS:

```
 .box:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: 43%;
      top: 30%;
      margin-top: -18px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 40px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent **rgba(7, 17, 241, 1);**    }
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jrrk6349/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an HTML special character arrow sign like this ➧ `&#10151;`
This way you could play with the color, size etc. the way you like

Here is the code:

`<div class="box">&#10151;</div>` this is for a separate div

And this is for an input. Please note that the type was changed to button

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 40px; bottom: 70px;">
<form action="abc.html" align="right" style="margin-right:100px ;   display:inline">
    <input type="button" class="box" value="&#10151;"></input>
</form>
```

And the CSS for both is

```
.box {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:pink;
color:blue;
text-align:center;
font-size:100px;
line-height:100px;
```

}

Comment: content : '21BA';     Yes I have even checked that by using the above tag, for which I am unable to change size of that special character.

Answer (score 1):

Ye u can simply using pseudo elemnts.

```css
.arrow {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #0000ff;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -80px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 80px solid #0000ff;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
.box {
  width: 165px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<a href="abc.html">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I need this arrow in a rectangle/box.

Comment: @rJ7 The code which you have mentioned earlier is awesome, but #href tag will lead to the next page/tab. I need the navigation should be done in the same page or tab, for that I guess we cant use the #href tag right ??

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the property for the `:after` pseudo-element that represent the head

```
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 18px;
  width: 8em;
  height: 6em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(77, 77, 77);
  color: #FF1919;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  /* before width 30% + before left position 20% */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```